# Creating a Mac app bundle

Tags: mac

I'm trying to create a Mac app bundle,

So I did this,

```
mkdir -p android.app/Contents/MacOS/
cp /path/to/myscript.sh android.app/Contents/MacOS/android
chmod +x android.app/Contents/MacOS/android
SetFile -t APPL android.app/Contents/MacOS/android
```

But when I do `open android.app`, it prompts me `The application cannot be opened because its executable is missing.`

That's totally weird. Anyone know how to fix that?

Running Mac OS 10.11.4

Comment: Mac app bundles are mysterious and weird.  I'd love to know the answer to this one, even though you **might** be better off asking/searching on the Apple stackexchange.

Comment: You are missing the Info.plist https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Comment: @Mark works when I added Info.list

Comment: Doing something to a system you don't know anything about, than discovering it doesn't work the way you expected, doesn't make it a weird system.

Comment: @Bachsau especially when well documented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App bundles must contain certain files as documented in [Apple's Bundle Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1)

The required files are

- Info.plist file - The information property list file is a structured file that contains configuration information for the application. The system relies on the presence of this file to identify relevant information about your application and any related files.
- Executable

So you need an Info.plist